# Get the nearest future date in a pandas dataframe from todays date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a DataFrame df_holiday and I want to select the row, which consists the next nearest date from todays date in order to extract the holiday name.

```
+----------+---------------------+
|   date   |        name         |
+----------+---------------------+
| 01012019 | Neujahr             |
| 06012019 | Heilige Drei Könige |
| 19042019 | Karfreitag          |
| 22042019 | Ostermontag         |
| 01052019 | Tag der Arbeit      |
| 10062019 | Pfingstmontag       |
+----------+---------------------+
```

If I do `type(df_holiday['date'][0])` it outputs `str`

Now I want to convert the column into datetime format using this:

```
import datetime
df_holiday['date'] = df_holiday['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%m%Y'))
```

First question here: Doc says it will return a datetime but in my case I get a timestamp, why?

```
type(df_holiday['date'][0])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

print(df_holiday['date'][0]
Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')
```

I found this post from  [dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550819/find-the-closest-date-from-today-in-a-list) who suggested the following routine:

```
min([d for d in df_holiday['date'] if d> datetime.date.today()], key=lambda s: 
          datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d%m%Y").date()-datetime.date.today())
```

Since the values in the date column are timestamps I got a

> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

I think this will work if its possible to convert the date column in a proper datetime format and not in timestamp format. 
How can I achieve this?
Or is there any better solution for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go: this will use todays date to filter by the holidays dates and take the next one and return its name. I have tried to make it as pythonic as possible. Any question, please ask.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
RawData="""
date|name
01012019|Neujahr            
06012019|Heilige Drei Könige 
19042019|Karfreitag          
22042019|Ostermontag         
01052019|Tag der Arbeit      
10062019|Pfingstmontag  
14092019|Internationale Feiertage

"""
holidays = pd.read_csv(StringIO(RawData), sep="|",dtype={'date': object})
holidays['date'] = holidays['date'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: dateutil.parser.parse(x[4:8]+x[2:4]+x[0:2]))
holidays[holidays.date > datetime.now()].head(1)['name']  #compare with todays date and get the next one
```

Result:

```
5    Pfingstmontag
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I need. But can you shortly explain the parser function? I do not get the parse(x[4:8]+x[2:4]+x[0:2]) section

Comment: Okay, you have 8 string characters for the date for example the first one : 01012019, 2019 is the year; so that is character 4 - 8 (four characters).

Comment: x[4:8]#year 
x[2:4]#month
x[0:2]#day

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a timestamp to date like so :

```
import datetime
readable = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1558272180)
print(readable)
2019-05-19T13:23:00
```

Here is a [link](https://timestamp.online/article/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-python) with several other ways to do it.

Comment: thanks but this doesn´t solve the problem. If i print the first row in my data column it returens Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), furthermore your suggestion returns readable as str and not as date

Comment: My bad you have remove the isoformat() to get a datetime type. I edited my anwser

Answer (score -1):

Since your `date` column is string, So converting it into date object

`import pandas as pd
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d%m%Y')`

This would convert `date` column to date type.

Next you could try the nearest date algorithm as stated above, this won't convert to timestamp format

Comment: this also returns a timestamp: df_holiday['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_holiday['date'], format='%d%m%Y') ---
type(df_holiday['date'][0]) --- 
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp