# Iterate over and perform function on python datetime objects

Tags: python, function, loops, csv, datetime

being inexperienced with Python I am unable to properly deal with the datetime objects, when wanting to iterate over them. I imported timestamps from a csv file and parsed them into datetime objects. Now I am unable to perform functions on them, because I get one error after the other. Please see my code, what causes the "TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable".

If there is no simple solution to my problem, can someone tell me how to save the datetime objects into a list?

The function of my code is inspired by this post, which works on date time objects from a list: [Getting the closest date to a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249220/getting-the-closest-date-to-a-given-date)

Thanks in advance.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

from dateutil.parser import parse

csvFile = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv')
column = csvFile['timestamp']

column = column.str.slice(0, 19, 1)

dt1 = datetime.strptime(column[1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print("dt1", dt1) #output: dt1 2010-12-30 15:06:00

dt2 = datetime.strptime(column[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print("dt2", dt2) #output: dt2 2010-12-30 16:34:00

dt3 = dt1 - dt2

print("dt3", dt3) #output: dt3 -1 day, 22:32:00



#parsing the timestamps as datetime objects works:
for row in range(len(column)):
timestamp = datetime.strptime(column[row], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print("timestamp", timestamp) #output (excerpt): timestamp 2010-12-30 14:32:00 timestamp 2010-12-30 15:06:00
```

## here error occurs:

```
base_date = dt1
def func(x):
    d = x[0]
    delta = d - base_date if d > base_date else timedelta.max
    return delta
min(timestamp, key = func)
```

Answer (score 0):

timestamp is an instance of  datetime.datetime,you should put it into a list or a tuple.
after correct,it should be like this `min([timestamp], key = func)`

Comment: This is something I had tried before and results in the "AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'toList'". I added myNewList = timestamp.toList() after parsing the timestamps.